# Mahler's theorem for certain refinements of binary forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

In 1933, Kurt Mahler proved the following: Let $F$ be a binary form with integer coefficients which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and has degree $d \geq 3$. Then the area $A_F$ of the region

$$\displaystyle \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : |F(x,y)| \leq 1 \}$$

is finite. Put
$$\displaystyle N_F(Z) = \#\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 : |F(x,y)| \leq Z\}.$$
Then the asymptotic relation

$$\displaystyle N_F(Z) = A_F Z^{\frac{2}{d}} + O_F\left(Z^{\frac{1}{d-1}} \right)$$
holds.

Indeed, the requirement that $F$ be irreducible can be replaced with $F$ having non-zero discriminant. Moreover, the implied constant of the big-$O$ term is now known to be bounded in terms of a power of the logarithm of the largest coefficient of $F$.

My question is the following: is there an analogue of Mahler's theorem  known for polynomials of the shape $F(x,y^k)$, where $F$ is a binary form of degree $d \geq 3$ with non-zero discriminant and $k \geq 2$ an integer?